# MSP430FR4133 Internal Temperature Sensor

Tags: c, microcontroller, msp430, iar

I am currently using the MSP430FR4133 in order to make an ultrasonic measurement system for the volume of a room and would like to be able to check the temperature of a room to work out the speed of sound before I carry out any calculations. 
I am trying to use the code in the "Out-the-Box Software Example" that uses the temperature sensor to display the temperature in Celsius and Fahrenheit. This folder is found at: http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSP-EXP430FR4133/latest/index_FDS.html.

My code is as follows:

main.c

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <driverlib.h>
#include "hal_LCD.h"
#include "InputOutput.h"
#include "Temp.h"
#include "Displays.h"

#define PORT1_VECTOR        (47 * 2u)
#define TIMER1_A0_VECTOR    (54 * 2u) 

char introduction[6] = "HELLO";

int main(void)
{
WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;               // Stop watchdog timer

tempInit();
InitInputs();
InitOutputs();
Init_LCD();
double speedofsound = tempInit();
displayScrollText(introduction);

// Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode
// to activate previously configured port settings
PMM_unlockLPM5();

while(1)
{
      double distance[3];
      double time[3];
      double volume = 0;

      displayLength();
      SW1();
      displayWait();
      time[0] = SW2();
      displayWidth();
      SW1();
      displayWait();
      time[1] = SW2();
      displayHeight();
      SW1();
      displayWait();
      time[2] = SW2();

      for(int i =0;i<3;i++)
      {
            distance[i] = time[i]*speedofsound;
      }

      volume = distance[0]*distance[1]*distance[2];
      displayVolume(volume);
    }
}
```

Temp.c

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <driverlib.h>
#include "hal_LCD.h"
#include "Temp.h"

#define CALADC_15V_30C  *((unsigned int *)0x1A1A)       // Temperature Sensor Calibration-30 C
#define CALADC_15V_85C  *((unsigned int *)0x1A1C)       // Temperature Sensor Calibration-85 C

volatile unsigned char * tempUnit = &BAKMEM4_H;
volatile int *degC = &BAKMEM5;                          // Celcius measurement
volatile unsigned char * tempSensorRunning = &BAKMEM3_H;      // Temp Sensor running flag
int deg;

Timer_A_initUpModeParam initUpParam_A1 =
{
    TIMER_A_CLOCKSOURCE_ACLK,               // ACLK Clock Source
    TIMER_A_CLOCKSOURCE_DIVIDER_1,          // ACLK/1 = 32768Hz
    0x2000,                                 // Timer period
    TIMER_A_TAIE_INTERRUPT_DISABLE,         // Disable Timer interrupt
    TIMER_A_CCIE_CCR0_INTERRUPT_DISABLE ,   // Disable CCR0 interrupt
    TIMER_A_DO_CLEAR                        // Clear value
};

Timer_A_initCompareModeParam initCompParam =
{
    TIMER_A_CAPTURECOMPARE_REGISTER_1,        // Compare register 1
    TIMER_A_CAPTURECOMPARE_INTERRUPT_DISABLE, // Disable Compare interrupt
    TIMER_A_OUTPUTMODE_RESET_SET,             // Timer output mode 7
    0x1000                                    // Compare value
};

double tempInit()
{
  *tempSensorRunning ^= 0x01;
  *tempSensorRunning =1;
  //Initialize the ADC Module
  /*
   * Base Address for the ADC Module
   * Use Timer trigger 1 as sample/hold signal to start conversion
   * USE MODOSC 5MHZ Digital Oscillator as clock source
   * Use default clock divider of 1
   */
  ADC_init(ADC_BASE,ADC_SAMPLEHOLDSOURCE_2,ADC_CLOCKSOURCE_ADCOSC,ADC_CLOCKDIVIDER_1);

ADC_enable(ADC_BASE);

//Configure Memory Buffer
/*
 * Base Address for the ADC Module
 * Use input A12 Temp Sensor
 * Use positive reference of Internally generated Vref
 * Use negative reference of AVss
 */
    ADC_configureMemory(ADC_BASE,ADC_INPUT_TEMPSENSOR,ADC_VREFPOS_INT,ADC_VREFNEG_AVSS);

    ADC_clearInterrupt(ADC_BASE, ADC_COMPLETED_INTERRUPT);

    // Enable the Memory Buffer Interrupt
    ADC_enableInterrupt(ADC_BASE,ADC_COMPLETED_INTERRUPT);

    ADC_startConversion(ADC_BASE, ADC_REPEATED_SINGLECHANNEL);

    // Enable internal reference and temperature sensor
    PMM_enableInternalReference();
    PMM_enableTempSensor();

    // TimerA1.1 (125ms ON-period) - ADC conversion trigger signal
    Timer_A_initUpMode(TIMER_A1_BASE, &initUpParam_A1);

    //Initialize compare mode to generate PWM1
    Timer_A_initCompareMode(TIMER_A1_BASE, &initCompParam);

    // Start timer A1 in up mode
    Timer_A_startCounter(TIMER_A1_BASE, TIMER_A_UP_MODE);

    // Delay for reference settling
    __delay_cycles(300000);

    while(*tempSensorRunning)
    {
        __bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits | GIE);                       // LPM3 with interrupts enabled
        //__no_operation();                                         // Only for debugger

        // Calculate Temperature in degree C and F
        signed short temp = (ADCMEM0 - CALADC_15V_30C);
        *degC =((long)temp * 10 * (85-30) * 10)/((CALADC_15V_85C-CALADC_15V_30C)*10) + 300;

        *tempSensorRunning = 0;
    }
    double speed = 331+0.6*(*degC);
    return speed;
    };
```

I have made slight adjustments to the code in order to find the speed of sound for the temperature of the room, however this code does not seem to work. I get a warning `a value of type "unsigned short volatile *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int volatile *"`(line 10 of Temp.c) which I don't think is effecting my code, however I am unsure on how to correct this.

When I set breakpoints within the code I is seen that at `if(*tempSensorRunning)`the code runs into an endless loop. Can anyone please give me some advice for this problem?

EDIT:

I have changed the code for Temp.c slightly to illustrate the suggested changes. Having set breakpoints throughout the code I can see that the problem is occuring at `signed short temp = (ADCMEM0 - CALADC_15V_30C);`. The code is stopping here and not moving past this point. The disassembly is staying at the point:

```
?reset_vector:
010000
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: no it's not correct

Comment: This question would be better if you pointed out the exact line that triggers the error (or warning) message from the compiler.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy sorry I forgot about that, I have made changes to this

Answer (score 1):

The variable `tempSensorRunning` is set to 1 in the line:

`*tempSensorRunning = 1;`

and never (at least in this code) cleared to 0, so that's where your infinite loop comes from.

This device is a 16-bit MCU, so `int` in this case is 16-bits long. In any case, this is confusing, so to be sure you're using the correct bit width for accesses (especially as you're accessing data via pointers), include `<stdint.h>` and be explicit:

- `uint8_t` for unsigned 8-bit numbers
- `uint16_t` for unsigned 16-bit numbers

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the code to solve the endless loop problem. However I don't think that was the problem, I have stated above where the problem seems to be happening. If you can help with this at all it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I assume the warning comes from this line:

```
volatile int *degC = &BAKMEM5;
```

Apparently BAKMEM5 is a short, not an int.  The way to correct it is to change the type of degC to `volatile short *`.  This fix may have ripple effects.  You have to use the right types consistently.

This is likely an actual bug and not just a warning you can ignore.

Comment: When changing this to `volatile short *` it comes up with a different warning. This warning is `a value of type "unsigned short volatile *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "short volatile *"`. I am unsure on why this error is coming up.

Comment: Based on your edit, it looks like the problem is that the MCU is being placed into a low power mode with (`__bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits | GIE);`), which stops the oscillator. To 'wake up', you need an interrupt service routine (presumably for the ADC), which I don't see in your code. If you remove the `__bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits | GIE);` line, the code should continue running, but you may stop getting conversion results (depending on the how the ADC is configured).

Comment: @EdKing this fixed the problem. I knew that it would go into low power at one point just didn't know when. Thank you very much, this problem has bee frustrating me for days!

Comment: @EdKing that's not right. LPM3 does not turn off the oscillator or ACLK, which is what OP is using. LPM3_bits = (SCG1+SCG0+CPUOFF), not like LPM4_bits = (SCG1+SCG0+OSCOFF+CPUOFF)